# How to grab HTML tags as well as the text between them and store in an object

Tags: java, regex, selenium-webdriver, automation, appium

I am working on a selneium-appium-java mobile web automation framework. I have a cucumber test that uses regex to accept some text and pass it further on as a parameter such as:

```
@Given("^user checks text \"([^\"]*)\" in footer$")
public void checkFooter(String footerText) {
    footerComponent.checkNote(footerText);
}
```

Here is how it currently is set up for finding basic text of a node in the FooterComponent class

```
    private final String FOOTER = "//div[contains(@class, 'footer')]";

    public void checkNote(String expectedText) {
    By note = By.xpath(FOOTER + "//div[@class='footer-footnote']");
    String actualText = getDriver().findElement(footerText).getText();
    assertEquals(actualText, expectedText, "Unexpected footer note");
}
```

Example of DOM that i need to validate expected result against:

```
<div class='footer'>
text1
<span class="copysymbol"></span>
text2
<span class="dot"></span>
text3
<span class="dot"></span>
text4
<span class="dot"></span>
</div>
```

Ive tried using the pattern from here but ive not been successful:
https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/how-extract-html-tag-string-regex-pattern-matcher-group

So basically i need to insert some text that checks for the presence of the tags (which represent special characters i need to check for) AND the text between them in the cucumber line and then have the java method check for the actual code by finding it with Xpath. Is there a way this can be done using regex via cucumber?

Comment: I think that using xPath to check HTML is far preferable to using a regex.  So maybe you can continue to use xPath here.

Answer (score 0):

I like to provide a stub as an answer since I have to agree that XPath is most appropriate than regex here.
Plus, if someone here gives you a complicated regex that does everything you want but is not maintainable by you.. what have you gained?

The following pattern matches the whole footer div. I cannot do much more since your description contains only one example and no variations.

[`<div class='footer'>.*?<span class="copysymbol"><\/span>.*?<span class="dot"><\/span>.*?<span class="dot"><\/span>.*?<span class="dot"><\/span>\s*<\/div>`](https://regex101.com/r/8W2sBg/1)

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "<div class='footer'>.*?<span class=\"copysymbol\"><\\/span>.*?<span class=\"dot\"><\\/span>.*?<span class=\"dot\"><\\/span>.*?<span class=\"dot\"><\\/span>\\s*<\\/div>";
final String string = "<div class='footer'>\n"
     + "text1\n"
     + "<span class=\"copysymbol\"></span>\n"
     + "text2\n"
     + "<span class=\"dot\"></span>\n"
     + "text3\n"
     + "<span class=\"dot\"></span>\n"
     + "text4\n"
     + "<span class=\"dot\"></span>\n"
     + "</div>";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.DOTALL);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```